# How to pick and choose the MS Office 365 app I want to download/install?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, installation, microsoft-office, microsoft-powerpoint

I'm a student and I have a student account at Microsoft where I can download/install Office for free.

However, on the Install page, I can only install ALL or none of the office apps.

[image: see screenshot]

**How do I pick and choose the MS Office 365 app I want to download/install?** For example, I only want to install Word, Excel, and PowerPoint.

**OR, is there a way to uninstall a particular app after I install the Office pack?**

Comment: This portal will only allow you to install all at once.

Comment: @pun do you know a place where I can pick and choose?

Comment: I haven't used it but think you should be able to use [this](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219423.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#Anchor_2) along with [this](https://officedev.github.io/Office-IT-Pro-Deployment-Scripts/XmlEditor.html). The process is providing the installer a custom configuration in the form of XML file specifying your needs

Comment: The deployment tool only works with ProPlus versions of Office (ie, not the 365/subscription versions). @ChairmanMeow for your version, I'm pretty sure it's all or nothing.